# Example of an XML DAO

Tags: java, xml, dao

I'm unsure of how I could write a DAO to write information to XML files. I know how to use Sax and JDOM but what I'd like to know is how the DAO could be initialized to set the XML file path. The CRUD-style methods shouldn't be an issue but if you have any further suggestions please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the path in?

```
interface thingyDAO {

    public void save(path, xmlStringOrWhatever)

    ....
}
```

EDIT -- or if it is constant, just put in the DAO class hierarchy somewhere, or you could configure it with properties.  Something like this should not slow you down -- do something that works and refactor when you need to...

Comment: Ok. I was trying to draw a parallel with how database DAOs function. Usually, the driver and data source are initialized in a Main class. On some class diagrams the DAO features a connection instance (which usually comes from a Connection singleton on basic implementations). Perhaps I could just set the directory path on a DAO instance and let it determine to what file name it should write. What do you think?

Comment: To add something, here's a link with code for a basic (without Spring) DAO pattern: http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-119237-le-pattern-dao-1-2.html

Comment: @james, many options, my answer has just one...if the path is a constant it could be a private field on the DAO, or a DAO superclass depending on your design.  As a note, DAO is just a paradigm for creating a layer for 'persistence', whether to a DB or a FS, and regardless of persisted format.  I use Spring pretty much exclusively, so all the connection details are handled by the framework....

Answer (score 1):

If the value is constant, make it a private static final String.  If for example it could change based on your deployment environment (dev/test/prod) you could use Spring and inject the value using a parameter.  Injection to singletons can be done using fields, methods and I believe constructors.